# Activate a ToggleButton based on the "down" state of four other ToggleButton 's

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Been stuck on this for a couple of days, decided to ask the kivy community!

Currently trying to figure out how to

-activate a ToggleButton based on the toggle state of four other ToggleButton s

Here is a picture of the interface:
[image]

Activating "down" state on Toggle1, Toggle2, Toggle3, and Toggle4 should activate MainToggle1

Here is what I have so far:

```
main.py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class ExternalTrigger(BoxLayout):
    buttonState = BooleanProperty(False)
    def on_activated_state(self, widget):
        if widget.state == "normal":
            self.buttonState = False
        elif widget.state == "down":
            self.buttonState = True

class BoxLayoutExample(BoxLayout):
    pass

class BoxLayoutApp(App):
    pass

BoxLayoutApp().run()
```

---

```
BoxLayout.kv

BoxLayoutExample:

<ExternalTrigger@BoxLayout>:
    ToggleButton:
        text: "MainToggle1"
        on_state: root.on_activated_state(self)
        disabled: root.on_activated_state(self)

<BoxLayoutExample@PageLayout>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        ExternalTrigger:
        GridLayout:
            size_hint: 2, 1
            cols: 2
            ToggleButton:
                background_color: (0,0,1)
                text: "Toggle1"
            ToggleButton:
                background_color: (0,1,0)
                text: "Toggle2"
            ToggleButton:
                background_color: (1,0,0)
                text: "Toggle3"
            ToggleButton:
                background_color: (7,1,3)
                text: "Toggle4"
```

Advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Going to explore using id: to solve this problem!

Comment: Try to summarize it in words (instead of picture) what exactly you want.

Comment: So what you pretend is to set state "down" in main ToggleButton only if the other four are down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `id` property and a custom class of `ToggleButton`.

The class you have to add:

```
class MyToggleButton(ToggleButton):
    # This method will check if all the ToggleButtons are "down" state
    def checkAllButtons(self, btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4):
        if (btn1.state == 'down') and (btn2.state == 'down') and (btn3.state == 'down') and (btn4.state == 'down'):
            return 'down'
        else:
            return 'normal'
```

In you `.kv` file add a custom property to the class `<ExternalTrigger@BoxLayout>:` and bind it to the state of the main ToggleButton:

```
<ExternalTrigger@BoxLayout>:
    custom: 'normal'
    ToggleButton:
        text: "MainToggle1"
        on_state: root.on_activated_state(self)
        disabled: root.on_activated_state(self)
        state: root.custom
```

Then add the `id` to each ToggleButton and evaluate `on_press` event if the four ToggleButtons are "down" (do this with the method created in the custom class).

Change all the four ToggleButtons you have to the folling:

```
MyToggleButton:
    id: but1  # Here obviously change the id, for example in ToggleButton2: id=but2
    background_color: (0,0,1)
    text: self.state
    on_press: ext.custom=self.checkAllButtons(but1,but2,but3,but4) #This remains the same for every ToggleButton
```